# PanelBar item with Ajax Action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a panelbar with some items and I want to set the action associated to them to be performed by Ajax.

Example code:

So far I have this (no ajax):

```
   @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
      .Name("left-menu-module")
      .Items(items =>
      {
              items.Add()
              .Text("<div class=\"text-item-container\"><span class=\"left-menu-module-level1-text\">" + "item1" + "</span></div>").Encoded(false)
              .ImageUrl("link to an icon")
              .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { width = 30 })
              .Action("Action1", "Controller");
              items.Add()
                  .Text("<div class=\"text-item-container\"><span class=\"left-menu-module-level1-text\">" + "item2" + "</span></div>").Encoded(false)
                  .ImageUrl("link to an icon")
                  .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { width = 30 })
                  .Action("Action1", "Controller");
      }))
```

This generate something like:

```
//...
<li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem">
    <a class="k-link k-header" href="/MyController/Action1">
    <img alt="image" class="k-image" src="link to an icon" width="30"><div class="text-item-container"><span class="left-menu-module-level1-text">item1</span></div>
    </a>
</li>
//...
```

But I would like to have something like:

```
//...
<li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem">
    <a class="k-link k-header" href="/MyController/Action1" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#target">
    <img alt="image" class="k-image" src="link to an icon" width="30"><div class="text-item-container"><span class="left-menu-module-level1-text">item1</span></div>
    </a>
</li>
//...
```

So, it's something similar to Ajax.ActionLink() helper.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does the Action("Action1", "Controller") have htmlAttributes parameter as method overload? If does pass data-ajax="true", etc, as parameter!

Comment: Well, I think that you should create an extension method, htmlHelper, for this Kendo-ui specific. Then you can add anything you want. Given that you know the generated HTML from this Action Method, the things can be less painful. Or, if you could put the ID for the anchor link, you should user jquery or something pure js to alter the element.

Comment: @Fals I could try with some htmlHelper method. Have you some example or link to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this using a function that was added in one of the recent Telerik updates:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
  .Name("left-menu-module")
  .Items(items =>
  {
          items.Add()
          .Text("<div class=\"text-item-container\"><span class=\"left-menu-module-level1-text\">" + "item1" + "</span></div>").Encoded(false)
          .ImageUrl("link to an icon")
          .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { width = 30 })
          .Action("Action1", "Controller")
          .LinkHtmlAttributes(/* Anonymous object OR Dictionary with the data- attributes */);
  }))
```

I'm using kendo version 2014.3.1316.440.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this..
Use content section inside div.

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
.Name("panelbar")
.ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
.Items(panelbar =>
{
    panelbar.Add().Text("Client Info")
        .Expanded(true)
        .Content(
        @<div>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Organization Detail", "OrganizationDetail", "SetupSystem", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divBody", LoadingElementId = "divLoading" }, new { id = "btnOrgDetails", @class = "list-group-item" })
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Benefit Center", "GetBenefitsOverview", "SetupSystem", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divBody", LoadingElementId = "divLoading" }, new { id = "btnBenefitCenter", @class = "list-group-item"})
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Services", "ServiceFilter", "SetupSystem", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divBody", LoadingElementId = "divLoading" }, new { id = "btnServices", @class = "list-group-item" })
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Key Dates", "GetKeyDatesOverview", "SetupSystem", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divBody", LoadingElementId = "divLoading" }, new { id = "btnKeyDates", @class = "list-group-item" })
        </div>);
}); )
```